# Bokeh patch() glyph method failing for fill-between using two lines with NaNs

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to fill between two lines using Bokeh. My two datasets contain sections of NaNs. The patch renders correctly for the last section of data, but fails for sections before any NaN blocks. The following example illustrates the problem:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import numpy as np

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)

mx = np.array(np.random.randint(20, 25, 30), dtype=float)
mx[7:11] = np.nan
mx[19:23] = np.nan

mn = mx-10

x = np.arange(0, len(mn))

wX = np.append(x, x[::-1])
wY = np.append(mx, mn[::-1])

p.patch(wX, wY)  

show(p)
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

I would like the first two parallel line sections to plot with a fill-between as the final section is plotting. Instead, these sections seem to be applying the patch just to the line segments themselves. I have a solution that creates individual patches by looping over each contiguous section of data, but it is too slow over many 100s of patches.

Answer (score 0):

For as far as i can tell, Bokeh renders the patches you provide correctly. Keep in mind that passing NaN's seperates individual patches. That makes it a bit strange that you pass multiple consecutive NaN's, which doesn't add anything. It's also a bit confusing to specify a valid X-coordinates together with a NaN Y-coordinate.

> Just as with line() and multi_line(), NaN values can be passed to patch() and patches() glyphs. In this case, you end up with single logical patch objects, that have multiple disjoint components when rendered

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

I have added the x,y coordinates to the first patch i get when running you code. Perhaps you intend something different, but Bokeh is rendering, what you specify, correctly.

[image]

Comment: My example was meant to present a simple case of my problem, although the lack of context may be confusing. My application is to time series data (thus the continuous x-axis values), with two lines: an upper line (max. daily air temperature) and a lower line (min. daily air temperature). I would like to fill between these two lines. However, there are occasional days or groups of days without any data. I would like to preserve these gaps, yet still apply the fill between to the sections of good data. In my example, I need the 1st and 2nd sections to fill-between like the 3rd section.